# Comma placement

Tags: punctuation, commas

Ok, just for fun, this sentence makes perfect sense when spoken, but in print, where would you put the commas?

I say at that that that that that that that refers to is not that that at all.

Comment: Good one!  Painfully tongue-twisting, but good nonetheless.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about punctuation of a contrived example.

Comment: I don't see "contrived" listed anywhere as a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: Folks, I think the key word here is 'example'... Does anyone have a non-contrived example?  Like perhaps a quote of someone actually saying that?

Answer (score 3):

I say(optional comma) at that, that "*that* that", that "*that* that" refers to, is not *that* that at all.

Comment: I have to believe that the use of quotation marks is cheating!  :P  The OP asked for commas!  (Then again, perhaps my usage of italics was cheating, too!)

Comment: @DavidM - I agree, I took liberties, as I was not limiting myself to OP's suggestion. But the commas *were* placed. Also, I was a bit embarrassed that your comment came up as I was submitting mine. Sorry. To rights, the upvote is yours. +1 to you. Feel free (I being sincere) to subtract mine. You were first. :)

Comment: Nonsense.  We've both made different postings here with regard to comma placement.  And, at that, I've up voted yours as well!  I believe that there can be different punctuations here changing the feeling of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I say at that, that *that*, that, *that* that refers to, is not *that* that, at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put the commas anyplace you please ...
... as long as it makes sense to ***you***, and represents what ***you*** hear.
And you shouldn't take anybody else's opinion about what you hear; it's ***your*** hearing.

[English punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf), like English spelling before printing, is personal and chaotic;
there are no rules, except the ones that work for ***you***.
Everybody who writes a lot eventually makes up rules for their own use and expectations for others'.
You may not have the same rules as others, however, so be aware that there are other conventions.

[This, for instance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html), is the convention that ***I*** use for commas.